# How do I pass a 3D VkImage to a compute shader without the data changing?

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, vulkan

I'm trying to pass a randomized 3D image of voxels to a compute shader, but when I run the shader the entire shader results in this:
[image: Compute Shader Output]

As you can see, this does not look anything like randomly generated voxels, except for the first and half of the second voxels. I honestly have absolutely no clue as to what is happening to the data. I know its not a problem with my compute shader output to the swapchain images because I checked if other compute shaders (like just a screen of noise etc.) would work, and they did. I've narrowed down the location of the bug to the copying of data from my `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec4>>>` to the `voxelImage` **or** it could be in the passing of the `voxelImage` to the compute shader.

Also I have checked that the generation of the voxels is not just generating what is seen on the screen. The vector of vec4s is indeed randomized, I guarantee the error is in either of the two places I have narrowed it down to.

I will only post the code for the `voxelImage` and `voxelImageView` creation, as well as the descriptors as that is likely where the bug is occuring. (posting the rest of the code would be unnecessarily excessive and it would be far too long)

**Voxel  Image Creation:**

```
void createVoxelImage() {

        VkDeviceSize imageSize = voxelDataInit.size();



        VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
        VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
        VmaAllocation stagingAllocation;
        createBuffer(imageSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT, stagingBuffer, stagingAllocation, stagingBufferMemory);

        void* data;
        vmaMapMemory(allocator, stagingAllocation, &data);
        memcpy(data, &voxelDataInit, imageSize);
        vmaUnmapMemory(allocator, stagingAllocation);

        
        
       
        VkDeviceMemory temp; 
        createImage(voxWidth, voxHeight, voxDepth, VK_IMAGE_TYPE_3D, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, voxelImage, voxelAllocation, VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY, temp, 5);
        //vkFreeMemory(device, temp, NULL);

        //VkDeviceMemory temp;
        //createImage(voxWidth, voxHeight, voxDepth, VK_IMAGE_TYPE_3D, VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT, voxelImage, voxelAllocation, VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_TO_GPU, temp, 5);

        transitionImageLayout(voxelImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT, VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT);
        copyBufferToImage(stagingBuffer, voxelImage, static_cast<uint32_t>(voxWidth), static_cast<uint32_t>(voxHeight), static_cast<uint32_t>(voxDepth));
        transitionImageLayout(voxelImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT, VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT);

        vmaDestroyBuffer(allocator, stagingBuffer, stagingAllocation);

    }
```

**Voxel Image View Creation:**

```
void createVoxelImageView() {
        VkImageViewCreateInfo viewInfo{};
        viewInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
        viewInfo.image = voxelImage;
        viewInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_3D;
        viewInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB;
        //viewInfo.flags = VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT;
        viewInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
        viewInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
        viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        viewInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

        
        
        if (vkCreateImageView(device, &viewInfo, nullptr, &voxelImageView) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create image view! (voxel)");
        }
    }
```

**Input of Data Into Shader**

```
layout(binding = 4, rgba8) uniform image3D voxels;
```

**Def of** `createImage` **:**

```
void createImage(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, uint32_t depth, VkImageType imgType, VkFormat format, VkImageTiling tiling, VkImageUsageFlags usage, VkImageLayout layout, VkMemoryPropertyFlags properties, VkImage& image, VmaAllocation& allocation, VmaMemoryUsage memUsage, VkDeviceMemory& imageMemory, int callNum) {
        VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo{};
        imageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
        imageInfo.imageType = imgType;
        imageInfo.extent.width = width;
        imageInfo.extent.height = height;
        imageInfo.extent.depth = depth;
        imageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
        
        imageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
        imageInfo.format = format;
        imageInfo.tiling = tiling;
        imageInfo.initialLayout = layout;
        imageInfo.usage = usage;
        imageInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
        imageInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
        imageInfo.flags = VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT;

        VmaAllocationCreateInfo vmaAllocInfo = {};
        vmaAllocInfo.usage = memUsage;
        vmaAllocInfo.requiredFlags = VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT;


        if (vmaCreateImage(allocator, &imageInfo, &vmaAllocInfo, &image, &allocation, nullptr) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(callNum));
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create image!");
        }
    }
```

**Def of** `transitionImageLayout` **:**

```
void transitionImageLayout(VkImage image, VkFormat format, VkImageLayout oldLayout, VkImageLayout newLayout, VkAccessFlagBits srcAccess, VkAccessFlagBits dstAccess, VkPipelineStageFlagBits srcStage, VkPipelineStageFlagBits dstStage) {
        VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

        VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
        barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        barrier.oldLayout = oldLayout;
        barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
        barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.image = image;
        barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
        barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
        

        VkPipelineStageFlags sourceStage;
        VkPipelineStageFlags destinationStage;

        if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL) {
            barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
            barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;

            sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
            destinationStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
        }
        
        else {
            if (srcStage == VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT) {
                barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
            }
            else {
                barrier.srcAccessMask = srcAccess;
            }
            barrier.dstAccessMask = dstAccess;

            sourceStage = srcStage;
            destinationStage = dstStage;
            //throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported layout transition.");
        }

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, sourceStage, destinationStage, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);

        endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
    }
```

**Def of** `copyBufferToImage` **:**

```
void copyBufferToImage(VkBuffer buffer, VkImage image, uint32_t width, uint32_t height, uint32_t depth){
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

    VkBufferImageCopy region{};
    region.bufferOffset = 0;
    region.bufferRowLength = 0;
    region.bufferImageHeight = 0;
    
    region.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    region.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;

    region.imageOffset = { 0, 0, 0 };
    region.imageExtent = {
        width,
        height,
        depth
    };

    

    vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(commandBuffer, buffer, image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region);

    endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
}
```

Comment: "*`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec4>>>`*" So... you have an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of `glm::vec4`. That's not something you can just throw at the GPU.

Comment: How should I be passing my data? I tried using conventional arrays but I kept getting stack overflow errors, understandably. I also I just copy that data to VkImage so technically I'm not throwing the pointers themselves, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `voxelDataInit` truly is a variable of type `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<glm::vec4>>>`, then `memcpy(data, &voxelDataInit, imageSize);` is never going to work. `&voxelDataInit` is a pointer to a `vector`. And pointers to `vector<T>`s are always the same size (ignoring the allocator itself): the size of 3 pointers.

Remember: a `vector<T>` is a *pointer* to an array of `T`s. Or rather, it's 3 pointers into that array. But regardless, a `vector<T>` is not *itself* an array of `T`s; it merely *owns* one. As such, copying the bytes of a `vector` will not copy the array itself.

Also, the `size` of the `vector` is just the number of elements, not the number of *bytes* in the array.

The best way to copy such a data structure is to stop using such a data structure. If you want a 3D array, then what you want is a *one-dimensional* array of size length*width*height. You can index any particular X,Y,Z component of the array by using the length,width,height to convert the 3D coordinate into a 1D coordinate.